# How to show source code in debug when using .lib and dll

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005

I am working in VS2005, 
I have a part of freeimage source code. I compile it into .lib and dll.
When I debug the program, I want to step into freeimage source code ,however vs2005 do not know which code is the freeimage.lib freeimage.dll compiled from, How can I let vs2005 know it.
I want to step into freeimage source code, when using its .lib and dll. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the code in a debug configuration and generate a program database file (.pdb) that contains the debug symbols:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyz1h6zd(VS.80).aspx

Then when you run the application use the debug version of the dll and make sure that Visual Studio can see the .pdb file.  Usually if everything is in one solution it can find it, otherwise you can put the .pdb file into the same directory as the dll.